# How to judge whether equation satisfy or not programmatically?

Tags: equation

We all know this is true:

```
(a+b)c = ca+b*c
```

But how to judge it in programme?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert the algebraic expressions in the same *format*.
Simplify both left and right expressions by applying the algrebraic rules.
For simple equations it won't be too hard to implement it.

Check out [Simplify any Algebraic Expression](http://www.webmath.com/anything.html). Tryout various expressions to get an idea.